# jQuery.ajaxStart equivalent in AngularJS | Ajax event handler in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to capture ajax  start and end event in a AngularJS. While using JQuery, one can use [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/), [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) etc to capture start,complete,end,fail events globally(or locally) in an application.

How can I globally track ajax events(start,end,failed) using AngularJS?
I am trying to show busy indicator and disable UI during an AJax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use $http whiile making ajax request in angulajs.  then you can use the http interceptor for showing the spinner. below are links of implementation for similar requirement.

[angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) or [angular-sham-spinner](https://github.com/harinair/angular-sham-spinner)

also read this [BLOG](http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/) which details how should that be implemented in case you decide to implement it yourself.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code for the http interceptor ?